input fields in datepicker comp not resetting to original values
i have an input field in a datepicker comp in react. i have made a clear filter button to erase the date from the input field. i have reset the state values for the input field in the onClick function but its not working.
import { useState } from "react";
import Datepicker from "tailwind-datepicker-react";

const dateOptions = (placeholder) => ({
  autoHide: true,
  clearBtn: true,
  clearBtnText: "Clear",
  maxDate: new Date("2030-01-01"),
  minDate: new Date("1950-01-01"),
  theme: {
    background: "bg-white",
    text: "text-black",
    input: "bg-white",
  },
  inputPlaceholderProp: placeholder,
});

const Notifications = () => {
  const [showStartDate, setShowStartDate] = useState(false);
  const [showEndDate, setShowEndDate] = useState(false);
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(null);
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(null);

  const handleStartDateChange = (date) => setStartDate(date);
  const handleEndDateChange = (date) => setEndDate(date);

  const handleSearch = () => {
    const params = {
      start_date: startDate?.toISOString()?.split('T')?.[0] || null,
      end_date: endDate?.toISOString()?.split('T')?.[0] || null,
    };
    console.log(params);
  };

  const clearSearch = () => {
    setStartDate(null);
    setEndDate(null);
    setShowStartDate(false);
    setShowEndDate(false);
    console.log("Search cleared"); 
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="flex mb-4">
        <Datepicker
          options={dateOptions("Start Date")}
          onChange={handleStartDateChange}
          show={showStartDate}
          setShow={setShowStartDate}
        />
        <Datepicker
          options={dateOptions("End Date")}
          onChange={handleEndDateChange}
          show={showEndDate}
          setShow={setShowEndDate}
          disabled={!startDate}
        />
        <button onClick={handleSearch} >
          Search
        </button>
        <button onClick={clearSearch} >
          Clear
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Notifications;

                

this clearSearch function when passed to onClick of a button is not working as desired. the startDate and endDate variables are not setting to null. so the input field dates as entered by the user are not getting erased.

Add value prop to the datepicker and put your date inside it when you set value to null date should be cleared
   <Datepicker
      options={dateOptions("Start Date")}
      onChange={handleStartDateChange}
      show={showStartDate}
      value={startDate} // add this
      setShow={setShowStartDate}
    />


this is not working. the state is getting updated but is not reflecting in the ui when i am setting it to null again.

here is a solution for anyone facing this issue


import Datepicker from "tailwind-datepicker-react";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const MyDatePicker = ({ onChange, canSelectDate, contractDate, disabled }) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const CLEAR_BUTTON_TEXT = "Effacer"; // Text for the clear button

  // Handle the change of the selected date
  const handleChange = (selectedDate) => {
    if (selectedDate === null) {
      onChange(null); // Clear the selected date if null
    } else if (!disabled) {
      onChange(selectedDate); // Update the selected date if not disabled
    }
  };

  // Handle close of datepicker popup
  const handleClose = (state) => {
    if (!disabled) {
      setShow(state); // Only toggle the popup if not disabled
    }
  };

  // Detect click events and check if the "Clear" button is clicked
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleClickOutside = (e) => {
      const target = e.target;

      // If clicking inside the datepicker, check if it’s the clear button
      if (
        target.tagName.toLowerCase() === "button" &&
        target.innerHTML === CLEAR_BUTTON_TEXT
      ) {
        console.log("Clear button clicked");
        handleChange(null); // Clear the date when the "Effacer" button is clicked
      }
    };

    // Add event listener for outside clicks
    window.addEventListener("click", handleClickOutside);

    // Cleanup event listener when component unmounts
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("click", handleClickOutside);
    };
  }, []);

  const options = {
    autoHide: true,
    todayBtn: true,
    clearBtn: true,
    todayBtnText: "Aujourd'hui",
    clearBtnText: CLEAR_BUTTON_TEXT, // Set the clear button text
    maxDate: new Date("2311-12-31"),
    minDate: new Date("1900-01-01"),
    theme: {
      background: "",
      todayBtn: "",
      clearBtn: "",
      icons: "",
      disabledText: "",
      text: "",
      input: "pl-10", // Adds padding-left for input
      inputIcon: "left-3",
      selected: "",
    },
    datepickerClassNames: "top-30",
    defaultDate: contractDate ? new Date(contractDate) : null,
    language: "fr",
    disabledDates: [],
    weekDays: ["Lu", "Ma", "Me", "Je", "Ve", "Sa", "Di"],
    inputNameProp: "date",
    inputIdProp: "date",
    inputPlaceholderProp:
      !contractDate && canSelectDate
        ? "Sélectionner une date"
        : "Date non disponible",
    inputDateFormatProp: {
      day: "numeric",
      month: "long",
      year: "numeric",
    },
    inputProps: {
      disabled: disabled, // Disable the input field based on the disabled prop
    },
    show: !disabled && show, // Only show the date picker if not disabled
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Datepicker
        options={options}
        onChange={handleChange}
        show={show}
        setShow={handleClose}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyDatePicker;



